# gzip change file ownership

Tags: unix, permissions, gzip

Here is a case I don’t understand.

I have a group `bar`, and this group has two users; `foo` and `bar`.

I have a `test.txt` file, `foo` is the owner and `bar` user only can read it.

However, if `bar` user run the `gzip` command to this file, the ownership changes from `foo` to `bar`.

Therefore, `foo` cannot touch this file any more.

Is this a security hole?

Logged in as `bar`

```
$ whoami
bar
$ cd /home/foo/test
$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 foo bar  4096 Jan  6 15:48 . 
drwxrwxr-- 5 foo bar  4096 Jan  6 15:48 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo    0 Jan  6 15:48 test.txt
$ gzip test.txt    
$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 foo bar 4096 Jan  6 15:50 . 
drwxrwxr-- 5 foo bar 4096 Jan  6 15:48 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bar  bar   29 Jan  6 15:48 test.txt.gz
$ uname -a
Linux 2.6.18-xenU-ec2-v1.2 #2 SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Logged in as a `foo`:

```
$ whoami
foo
$ touch test.txt.gz 
touch: cannot touch `test.txt.gz': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 8):

Its not a security hole. Gzip creates a new file and removes the old one. This is governed by the directory permissions and not the permissions on the file. If you remove write permission from the directory your test.txt will be safe from user bar.

The full process with respect to security looks like this:

1. Gzip uses read permission on original file to obtain a read-only file handle on original file.
2. Use write permission on directory to create new, empty file.
3. Read data from original file and write compressed data to new file
4. Delete old file using write permission on directory.

Answer (score 4):

`gzip` does not change the ownership of a file.  It creates a *new* file (which, by the nature of how Unix-like systems work, is owned by the user running the `gzip` command) and deletes the original file.

If you want the newly created `test.txt.gz` file to have the same user and group ownership as the `test.txt` file, you'll need to use `chown` -- and on most systems, that means you'll need root access.  User `bar` ordinarily *cannot* create a file owned by `foo‘.

(`gzip` can and does set the permission bits on the newly created `.gz` file to the same as those on the input file, and if you run it as `root` it will also use `chown` to set the owner. Source: I just tried it.)

Answer (score 3):

That means you'are a member of a different group. `gzip` creates a new file with your default group. The original file is removed.

HTH

Comment: I think he's wondering why it's owned by the user who runs `gzip`.

Comment: gzip can create a new file with directory ownership, but it shuould not be able to remove the existing file with read permission only.

Comment: @bighostkim: yes, it should, as file removal is a modification of the parent directory, which `bar` does have write access to.

Comment: What's the solution to OP's question?